# I'm trying to turn an array into a hash. Array items = indexes. Values of strings = string.length Values of integers = integer^2

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

```
myarray = ["Hello", 5, "Hi"]

def arrayToHash(array)
  newHash = Hash.new()

  array.each do |x|
    if x.is_a? String
      newHash[x.to_sym] = x.length
    elsif x.is_a? Integer
      newHash[x] = x*x
    else
      newHash[x] = nil
    end
  end
end

arrayToHash(myarray)
puts newHash
```

I'm getting `"undefined local variable or method 'newHash' for #<Context:0x7a58c8>"`

I'm a novice so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, but it just creates `newHash` inside the method.  It's a local variable that goes away when the method returns.  So you want the method to `return` the value:

```
def arrayToHash(array)
  newHash = Hash.new()

  array.each do |x|
    if x.is_a? String
      newHash[x.to_sym] = x.length
    elsif x.is_a? Integer
      newHash[x] = x*x
    else
      newHash[x] = nil
    end
  end
  return newHash
end
```

And then you have to assign the return value to something when you call the method:

```
myHash = arrayToHash(myarray)
```

A couple of improvements, or at least changes to make it more idiomatic Ruby.

1. This is purely cosmetic, but Rubyists prefer `names_like_this` over `namesLikeThis`.  So `array_to_hash`, `my_array`, etc.
2. If all you want is a plain empty hash, you can use `{}` instead of `Hash.new()`.
3. In general, any time you find yourself creating a new object and then looping over something to add things to that object, you can do the same job with a single call to `map` or `reduce`.  In this case:

   ```
   my_hash = my_array.reduce({}) do |new_hash, x|
     if x.is_a? String
      new_hash[x.to_sym] = x.length
     elsif x.is_a? Integer
       new_hash[x] = x*x
     else
       new_hash[x] = nil
     end
     new_hash
   end
   ```

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer! :) I will definitely make all of those improvements!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're pretty close. This is how I would do it:

```
def array_to_hash(array)
  array.reduce({}) do |result, item|
    if item.is_a? String
      result.merge(item.to_sym => item.length)
    elsif item.is_a? Integer
      result.merge(item => item * item)
    end
  end
end

array_to_hash(["Hello", 5, "Hi"])
=> {:Hello=>5, 5=>25, :Hi=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
def array_to_hash(array)
 rb_hash = Hash.new do |hash, key|
                   if key.is_a? String
                      hash[key.to_sym] = key.length
                   elsif key.is_a? Integer
                      hash[key] = key ** 2
                   else
                      nil
                   end
           end
 array.each do |elem| rb_hash[elem] end
 rb_hash
end
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. For `else`, don't you want `hash[key] = nil`?

Answer (score 0):

`newHash` is a local variable of `arrayToHash` method, and it is only valid and accessible from the inside. You might want to call it from inside the method, maybe right before you get out of it.

```
myarray = ["Hello", 5, "Hi"]

def arrayToHash(array)
  newHash = Hash.new()

  array.each do |x|
    if x.is_a? String
      newHash[x.to_sym] = x.length
    elsif x.is_a? Integer
      newHash[x] = x*x
    else
      newHash[x] = nil
    end
  end

  puts newHash # =>{:Hello=>5, 5=>25, :Hi=>2}
end

arrayToHash(myarray)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more variant:

```
def array_to_hash(array)
  array.each_with_object({}) do |x, hash|
    case x
    when String
      hash[x.to_sym] = x.length
    when Integer
      hash[x] = x*x
    else
      hash[x] = nil
    end
  end
end

array_to_hash( ["Hello", 5, "Hi"] )
  #=> { :Hello => 5, 5 => 25, :Hi => 2 }
```

I have changed some of your variable names to conform with Ruby's [naming convention](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_names.html).  You don't have to do that, but most Rubyists follow the convention.